# Opening a file in C using fopen

Tags: c, file-io, input

I'm attempting to open a file in C using fopen but I am having a fairly odd problem. If I do this it works perfectly fine:

```
ptr_file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
```

However if I try this it doesn't work

```
char file_name[20];    
printf("Enter file name");
scanf("%s",file_name);

ptr_file = fopen(file_name, "r");
```

The value of file_name itself is stored in a simple character array and I really don't see any difference here between the first and the second implementation if you enter the same file name. I feel like I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: use fgets instead of scanf for input, then remove last character which is a \n. using scanf to read strings is a pain with risk of buffer overrun. with fgets you tell how big your buffer is and it stops reading after that size

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Have you tried to print out `file_name` to see what it contains?

Comment: @JimRhodes meant -- printf("%s\n", file_name);  You may have a trailing \n character in the file_name string, for example.

Comment: try `perror("fopen");`

Comment: @jim (either): better would be `printf ("[%s]\n", file_name);`, so any trailing space or return is visible. (.. perhaps not `\r` though, depending on the terminal type..).

Comment: Forgive the obvious, but `FILE *ptr_file = fopen(file_name, "r");`? To cure any trailing `newline` after the read, use `scanf("%[^\n]%*c, file_name);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of whether there is a trailing `\n`, that would be skipped as whitespace. Here is a quick example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char file_name[20];

    printf ("\nEnter a filename: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", file_name);

    FILE *ptr_file = fopen(file_name, "r");

    if (!ptr_file)
        fprintf (stderr, "\nError: failed to open '%s'\n\n", file_name);
    else
        printf ("\n  Successfully opened file: '%s'\n\n", file_name);

    /* do stuff with file */

    if (ptr_file) fclose (ptr_file);

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/fileopen

Enter a filename: tolowercnvsn.c

  Successfully opened file: 'tolowercnvsn.c'
```

It works equally well with:

```
scanf("%s", file_name);
```